# Accessing template class from parent namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17, c++-templates

I am trying to specialize class from parent namespace defined in nested namespaces.

```
namespace A
{
    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct AStruct;
}

namespace A::B
{
    template<>
    struct A::AStruct<double>
    {
        using K = int;
    };
}
```

I get the following error when I do that.

```
error: declaration of 'struct A::AStruct<double>' in namespace 'A::B' which does not enclose 'A'
   10 |     struct A::AStruct<double>
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I specialize `AStruct` from inner namespace?

I tried it in compiler explorer, here is the [link](https://godbolt.org/z/aKKvbWaqs)

Thanks.

Comment: As the error message suggested, you can only do that in an enclosing namespace, not in the inner namespace.

Comment: Why do you want such specialization under `A::B`? What about an alias or using inheritance for that?